# All nearby routers are blocking mine

Tags: wifi, router, internet

There are so many routers nearby and they are on all available channels and blocking mine. I have a cheap router, I cannot afford a better one and I cannot run a cable across the room. Every router nearby is blocking mine and on most games i have over 1000 ping and i cannot play. Could anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a security-related question. Also, it's unclear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: This question belongs on [SU], but I'm sure it has been answered there in many variations.

Answer (score 1):

From your description the problem doesn't sound like malicious activity, but rather the common issue of wireless interference that occurs when there are too many wireless networks in a given location. When the channel you are using is "busy," meaning another access point or client is transmitting, you must wait until the channel is clear again before you can transmit. This results in high and very variable ping times.

There are two potential solutions to this. The first is to check if you are using the 5Ghz band, assuming both your access point and your WiFi adapter support it. The 5Ghz band is generally less congested than the 2.4Ghz band and supports faster speeds, with the tradeoff being worse signal penetration through walls. You can use WiFi Analyzer tools on your phone or computer to check which band you are using.

The second solution is to switch to a wired connection, but you seem to have already ruled out that possibility. Wired connections will virtually always be faster and more reliable than wireless ones.

Comment: There is a 3rd obvious solution and that is to create an aerial modification to focus the signal to the required side of the room. These are easy and cheap to create, a cardboard tube and some silver foil is all that is needed. [Try this search for ideas](https://www.google.com/search?q=wifi+aerial+booster)